# how can I make sure a dropdownlist's list is always dropped down rather than up

Tags: c#, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to show dropdownlist always to down. (Is it posible?)

If bottom space is less then the height of dropdown list it's show list to up.

I want to show list always to down.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by adding the following attribute to your CSS class of your dropdown list:

```
.drop-down {
    top:100%; 
}
```

The same can be used to force the list to go upwards: `bottom: 100%;`

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/1714/).

---

**EDIT:**

The standard HTML form Select Option  (`<select><option> <option></select>`) can not be manipulated to expand into a certain direction. You'll have to write your own custom dropdown menu with JavaScript  to implement this functionality.

After a quick browse I've noticed that others have struggled with the problem you're having. And apparently the following CSS code seems to fix it in some cases.

```
select { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: dont need for creating menu but for Dropdown list (Select Option)

Comment: I've edited my answer, hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the `attr size` using jQuery like so

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ou5n9u3y/

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    var dropdownOptions = $('.dropdown-selector').find('option').length;
    $('.dropdown-selector').attr('size', dropdownOptions);
});
```

Comment: This example doesn't use Materialize.css.