# Materialize css force select/options to always drop down, not up

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm working with [Materialize.css](https://materializecss.com/) and I have a form with some select/option drop-down menus. I have them all working fine except I notice that depending on the window size sometimes the menus will drop-up instead of drop-down, which creates UI/UX issues. Is it possible to force these select/option menus to always drop down?

HTML

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select a Number</label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('select').material_select();
```

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579795/how-can-i-make-sure-a-dropdownlists-list-is-always-dropped-down-rather-than-up :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I make sure a dropdownlist's list is always dropped down rather than up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579795/how-can-i-make-sure-a-dropdownlists-list-is-always-dropped-down-rather-than-up)